# C# and AForge - Use of unassigned local variable edgePoints

Tags: c#, variables, local

I'm trying to compile this code (the last one):
http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/blobs_processing.html

but it throws: **Use of unassigned local variable 'edgePoints'**  ..

here is the code:

```
        BlobCounter blobCounter = new BlobCounter();
        blobCounter.ProcessImage(image23);
        Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation();
        GrahamConvexHull hullFinder = new GrahamConvexHull();
        BitmapData data = image23.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, image23.Width, image23.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, image23.PixelFormat);
        foreach (Blob blob in blobs)
        {
            List<IntPoint> leftPoints, rightPoints, edgePoints;
            blobCounter.GetBlobsLeftAndRightEdges(blob, out leftPoints, out rightPoints);
            edgePoints.AddRange(leftPoints);
            edgePoints.AddRange(rightPoints);
            List<IntPoint> hull = hullFinder.FindHull(edgePoints);
            Drawing.Polygon(data, hull, Color.Red);
        }
        image23.UnlockBits(data);
```

And this is the line that he has problem with:

```
            edgePoints.AddRange(leftPoints);
```

I tied to assign Null to edgePoints but it failed:

```
List<IntPoint> leftPoints, rightPoints, edgePoints= null;
```

**What's the problem?** I didn't modify source code so everything should work..

Comment: That code really is wrong, maybe should tell the owners of the site about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to, well - assign a value to it:

```
List<IntPoint> leftPoints, rightPoints, edgePoints;
edgePoints = new List<IntPoint>();
```

Before you call method on that instance.

Your `leftPoints` and `rightPoints` are probably initialized by

```
blobCounter.GetBlobsLeftAndRightEdges(blob, out leftPoints, out rightPoints);
```

call (note the `out` keywords), but `edgePoints` isn't - you need to do that yourself.

Comment: thanks it worked! Although it's strange that developers put uncompilable code

Comment: @Alex: that is strange indeed.

Comment: by any chance could you guys help me out with Blob detection problem, when I'm trying to detect characters - "i" is detected as two objects - "I" and "dot"

Comment: @Alex: I'm sure somebody can - if you have a new question, just go ahead and ask it. On a side note, if you're trying to detect letters, are you sure blob detection is right way to go ("i" *is in fact 2 blobs* - line and dot)..?

Comment: yes, I'm going to get each blob as a bitmap and to compare each one of them to the "original" letter. If pixel color matches => letter recognized. As for "i" problem - I've thought of merging two Blobs, that are located on the same X coordinates!! Unfortunately I don't know how to implement it as for now. As for "spaces" - I can make up a rule that if "space between blobs" >= "some int" then add space.